# Concrete example of a particular 3-dimensional Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm reading over the classification of 3-dimensional complex Lie algebras, and have come to the classification of a particular Lie algebra spanned by $\{x,y,z\}$ satisfying the relations $$[x,y] = y, \; [x,z] = y+z, \; [y,z]=0$$

Seeking to find a concrete example of such a Lie algebra (in particular, a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$), I adapted another example to obtain the subalgebra spanned by 
\begin{align*}
x=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -1 \\
  0 & 0 & -1
 \end{pmatrix}, \; \; \;
y=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}, \; \; \;
z = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & -1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
which satisfies the above relations. However, I was wondering if a "nicer" example existed, and/or how to derive such an example.

Edit: I managed to find the following subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$, derived by considering the matrices of $\text{ad}(x)$, $\text{ad}(y)$ and $\text{ad}(z)$:

\begin{align*}
x=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}, \; \; \;
y=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}, \; \; \;
z = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  -1 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: not a representation in $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$, but: you can represent your Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ by linear operators acting on (say smooth) functions on $\mathbb R$, via $x\cdot f=df/dt$, $y\cdot f=e^tf$, $z\cdot f=te^tf$ ($t$ is the variable of $f$) (to make the space smaller, take for $f$'s just polynomials in $t$ and $e^t$). Another representation is by vector fields on $\mathbb R^2$: $y\mapsto\partial/\partial s$, $z\mapsto\partial/\partial t$, $x\mapsto(s+t)\partial/\partial s+t\partial/\partial t$ ($s,t$ the coordinates on $\mathbb R^2$)

Comment: What does "nicer" mean?

Comment: My first thought would be to put the bracket $[a,b]=ab-ba$ on the associative ring $\Bbb C[x,y,z]/(xy-yx-y,xz-zx-y-z,yz-zy,x^2,z^2)$ and then find matrices representing it. That gave me exactly the second representation you gave :) That seems like a general strategy with algebras and relations that would work in most cases.

Comment: I don't feel confident enough to say so because I'm not very familiar with Lie theory, but maybe one can conclude all Lie algebras satisfying those relations look like that quotient ring?

Comment: @ rghthndsd: yeah, I thought that might get brought up when I asked the question. Roughly speaking, I meant an example where the matrices looked simpler, or one where it was clear where the matrices came from (as per my edit). 

@ rschwieb: I see how that works, but where do you get that quotient ring from?